# Hide stock inventory option for non admin user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In wordpress e-shop (woocommerce) is it possible to hide/remove option stock inventory in products tab  if the user is not admin? My client who is admin doesnt want that shop manager would be able to costumize stock inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove Invertory tab

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_inventory_tab', 10, 1);

function remove_inventory_tab($tabs){
    if is ..
     unset($tabs['inventory']);
    endif
  return($tabs);
}
```